# Angular how to load component after user location found

Tags: angular, leaflet

I want to delay the component's loading until the user's location is found. I defined a child routes. The project has a map and an information panel. The map and the information panel are working with latitude and longitude. I used leaflet map. I created a resolver but not working as I expected. Here, 'geo' is returning undefined. Where is the mistake?

**HTML**

```
<div class="container-fluid h-100">
    <div class="row h-100">
        <div class="col-lg-7">
            <app-map></app-map>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-5 h-100">
            <div class="tab-content">
                <router-outlet></router-outlet>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**ROUTE**

```
export const appRoutes: Route[] = [
{
    path: 'info', component: InfoComponent, resolve: {geo: GeolocationService}, children: [
        {path: 'register', component: RegisterComponent},
        {path: 'list', component: ListComponent}
    ]
}];
```

**Geolocation service**

```
  export class GeolocationService implements Resolve<any> {

    constructor() {
    }

    resolve(): Observable<any> {
        return this.findLocation();
    }

    findLocation = () => {
        let coords;
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(position => {
                if (position.coords) {
                    coords = {lat: position.coords.latitude, lng: position.coords.longitude};
                    return coords;
                } else {
                    coords = {lat: 11, lng: 11};
                    return coords;
                }
            });
        } else {
            coords = {lat: 11, lng: 11};
            return coords;
        }
    };
}
```

**InfoComponent**

```
export class InfoComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor() {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.route.data.subscribe(data => {
        console.log('data', data);
    });
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would find it suspicious if the code even compiles. You should return a Promise from findLocation otherwise nothing will happen.

```js
export class GeolocationService implements Resolve<any> {

    resolve(): Promise<{lat: number, lng:number}> {
        return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(position => {
                if (position.coords) {
                    resolve({lat: position.coords.latitude, lng: position.coords.longitude});
                } else {
                    reject(new Error('browser did not return coordinates'));
                }
            });
        } else {
            reject(new Error('browser does not support geolocation api'));
        }

        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer when user blocked location resolver not working